# Ambiguous overload for 'operator==' with own class and std::string_view

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, operator-overloading, name-lookup

I created a class named `MyClass` in `namespace N`. Now I define a global `operator==` in `namespace N`.

```
namespace N
{
class MyClass
{
// member function begin()
// member function end()
// content omitted
}

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const MyClass& a_mc, const T& a_other)
{
    using namespace std;
    return std::equal(a_mc.begin(), a_mc.end(), begin(a_other));
}
}
```

This results in other code failing to compile with (included-from-stack omitted):

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator==' (operand types are
>   'std::basic_string_view' and 'const char [3]')
>
> note: candidate: 'bool N::operator==(const N::MyClass&, const T&)
>   [with T = char [3]]'
>
> note: candidate: 'constexpr bool
>   std::operator==(std::basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits>,
>   std::__detail::__idt >) [with
>   _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::__detail::__idt > =
>   std::basic_string_view]'   479 |
>   operator==(basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __x

Why is `N::operator==` even considered?

--

Edit first code that hit the problem was

```
bool N::MyClass::f(const std::string_view& a_thing)
{return a_thing.substr(0,2) == "XY";}
```

--

Minimal working example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>

namespace N
{
        struct MyClass
        {
                MyClass() noexcept = default;
                template<typename T,
                        typename = std::void_t<decltype(T{}.data())>,
                        typename = std::void_t<decltype(T{}.size())>>
                MyClass(const T& a_source)
                {}

                const char* begin() const { return 0; } // stub
                const char* end() const { return 0; } // stub
                bool f(const std::string_view& a_thing);
        };

        template<typename T>
        bool operator==(const MyClass& a_mc, const T& a_other)
        {
            using namespace std;
            return std::equal(a_mc.begin(), a_mc.end(), begin(a_other));
        }

        bool MyClass::f(const std::string_view& a_thing)
        {
                return a_thing.substr(0,2) == "XY";
        }
}
```

Compile with

> g++ -std=c++17 example.cpp

Comment: `N::operator==` is considered for what? please provide a [mcve].

Comment: we need a complete reproducible example. I do know what code I have to add to get a similar error, but I have no clue what code you have, so it is impossible to answer in a meaningful way

Comment: does `MyClass` have a converting constructor?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/2J6idF

Comment: `using namespace std; return std::equal(...);` Pretty meaningless, isn't it? Normally you'd have `using std::equal; return equal(...);`.

Comment: `MyClass` has a constructor that takes a `std::string_view` probably. Show your code.

Comment: This is stil not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyClass has a template constructor that works with `std::string_view`.

Since the constructor is not marked `explicit` the compiler is allowed to use it for implicit conversions.

That means that when you do

```
bool N::MyClass::f(const std::string_view& a_thing)
{return a_thing.substr(0,2) == "XY";}
```

the compiler is allowed to convert `a_thing.substr(0,2)` to a `MyClass` and then it could be used to call your `bool operator==`.

One way to avoid things like this is to make the constructor of `MyClass` explicit.

```
template<typename T,
    typename = std::void_t<decltype(T{}.data())>,
    typename = std::void_t<decltype(T{}.size())>>
    explicit MyClass(const T& a_source)
    {}
```

Comment: Why does the error message state that the operand types are  'std::basic_string_view' and 'const char [3]'?

Comment: The left-hand-side is a `std::string_view` and the right hand side is `"XY"` which get deduces as `const char [3]` by the template.

Comment: @std_unordered_map Another way to put it is that if your `operator==` did not exist `"XY"` would be converted to a `std::string_view`. But since both that and your `operator==` requires 1 conversion to work it is ambiguous which one should be preferred.